# Не могу привязать данные к всплывающему окну (Angular, ngDialog.)

Tags: javascript, mvc, angularjs

Через ng-repeat вывожу список элементов, у каждого элемента есть свои параметры.
По нажатию на элемент должно открываться всплывающее окно (используем ngDialog), в котором можно сделать опредленный манипуляции с параметрами этого элемента и затем отправить их например.

У элементов атрибут ng-click указывает на вызов:

```
ngDialog.open({
template: '/views/template.html',
controller: 'NeededCtrl',
controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

После controllerAs я пытался добавлять "scope: {параметры}", также пробовал resolve, но и в том и втом случае ничего не получается и сыпятся ошибки. Например j.$new is not a function и тому подобное.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать объекты со значениями контроллеру модального окна и добраться до них изнутри.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ссылку на директиву добавьте, пожалуйста. Было бы здорово увидеть модель и хотя бы кусочек `view`.

Comment: а еще лучше [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте параметр `data` (в контроллере диалога данные можно использовать через `$scope.ngDialogData`).

[документация здесь](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#data-string--object--array)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Мое утверждение основано на официальной документации к ngDialog https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Comment: @user1907691 у гитхаба рядом с основными пунктами при наведении на них (hover) появляется цепочечка.. нажав на которую можно получить ссылку (в URL) непосредственно на пункт.... вот так `https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#data-string--object--array`  можете подправить ответ, чтоб человек не искал по слову `data` а сразу прыгнул на неё

Comment: Алексей, спасибо!